# Proof of Borel-Cantelli Lemma explanation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-explanation, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I am trying to follow the proof of the Borel-Cantelli lemma as shown below:

> [image]

Could you please explain me how to go from:

> Thus $\sum \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} 1_{A_n}$ is almost surely finite

to:

> Hence $P(A) = 0$

In other words, could you please explain the relationship between the set $A$ and the function $\sum \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} 1_{A_n}$ ?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: what book is this from ?

Comment: It is Measure Integration and Real analysis by Axler, 2020

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge: By monotone convergence $\int_\Omega \sum_n\mathbb{1}_{B_n}\,d\mu =\sum_n\int_\Omega\mathbb{1}_{B_n}\,d\mu=\sum_n\mu(B_n)$. So, if $\sum_n\mu(B_n)<\infty$, then $f:=\sum_n\mathbb{1}_{B_n}$ is $\mu$-integrable. this means that $f$ is finite $\mu$-a.s. (Recall that if $\phi$ is $\mu$-integrable, then $\phi$ is finite $\mu$-a.s.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have :
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty 1_{A_n}(\omega) = \infty  &\Longleftrightarrow 1_{A_n}(\omega) = 1 \text{ for infinitely many } n \\
 &\Longleftrightarrow \omega\in A_n \text{ for infinitely many } n \\
&\Longleftrightarrow \omega \in A
\end{align}

Therefore, if $\mathbb P(\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1_{A_n} < \infty) = 1$, you have $\mathbb P(A)= 0$.

Comment: Merci pour ton aide =). But could you please explain me the meaning of $P(\sum \limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} 1_{A_n} \lt \infty)$ please ? it is a set or a function ?

Comment: It's a shorthand for $P(\{\omega : \sum_{n=0}^\infty 1_{A_n}(\omega) < \infty \})$